# PHP API That fetches and displays a row form sql database

Tags: php, sql, database, api

I have been trying to code an API that when a button is pressed on a program is fetches and displays a random row from a mysql database in this format - Text:Text - My code so far doesn't seem to work? Have a look:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","user","pass","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `data_submit` ORDER BY     RAND() LIMIT 0,4;");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['name'];

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Please help!!! It's really annoying.

Thanks

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Well you fetch array of rows, so you can't just use $row['name']. Loop over it and get the rows it found.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM data_submit ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it is a thing, yes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: MightyPork said the answer.Your question is about the arrays.The query fetches a single value array so you can't read it without loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` extensions. You can't use them interchangeably, you must use one or the other (since `mysql_*` is deprecated, as per my comment above, you should consider using MySQLi). You also must loop over the result, since you're returning an array:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","user","pass","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `data_submit` ORDER BY     RAND() LIMIT 0,4;");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['name'];
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds ;)

Comment: this will display if the row is like this "text:text" right?

Comment: @user3786334 It should, if that's the way it's being stored in your database. Why not just try it and see instead?

Comment: 'data_submit' could you confirm what this part is please?

Comment: @user3786334 What are you talking about? Where did you get that string from? You need to give more context.

Comment: @user3786334 What do you mean "*confirm what this part is*"? Do you not know?

Comment: if I knew, I wouldn't be asking..

Comment: @user3786334 It specifies the table you're querying from the database. You really need to brush up on your [SQL syntax](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-syntax.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You start with a `mysqli_connect` but switch to the `mysql_query` (the non-improved version). You should stick to the `mysqli`-library: `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_fetch_array`

Answer (score 1):

*Sidenote* your current query will be very slow on larger tables, here is a faster one.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id >= ( SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM table ) 
ORDER BY id LIMIT 4
```